# How to avoid using position:absolute in stylesheets for aura components due to security concerns as mentioned in the ISV guide

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, isv, security-review

I'm trying to pass security review for my managed package.  I have to a security issue to address: Unsafe CSS position declaration: position: absolute;

The Salesforce Platform tries to ensure that each namespace is an isolated sandbox, but isolation can’t always be guaranteed. Where a namespace isolation breach occurs, one component can steal clicks from another component, or otherwise interfere with another component’s intended use. To prevent this type of abuse, don’t use CSS directives known to be incompatible with style isolation in your components.

CSS Example:

```
// This CSS code is vulnerable because it uses absolute positioning, which is incompatible with style isolation.
#some_element {
   position: absolute;
   right: 80px;
   top: 160px;
}
This CSS code prevents the vulnerability by using relative positioning.
#some_element_revised {
   position: relative;
   right: 80px;
   top: 160px;
}
```

That is from the ISV guide.

This is the css markup of my component where absolute position is used:

```
.THIS .atcb-link span.lightningPrimitiveIcon:before,
.THIS .atcb-link > *:before {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Looking around SLDS, I did come across this:

```
<div class="demo-only slds-grid" style="height:10rem;width:20rem;padding:2rem">
  <div class="slds-is-absolute">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:1rem;left:1rem;border:1px solid red;background:#f4f6f9">An element with absolute positioning is positioned relative to its closest ancestor with relative positioning. If no other positioning values are given (
      <code>top, right, bottom, left</code>) it will start its positioning relative to where it is in the flow of the page.</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would wrapping my component with a parent div and setting class="slds-is-absolute" be a solution to my problem? To be honest, I'm not really quite sure why slds-is-absolute exists since we're still declaring absolute positioning in the child element.  But maybe there's more to it that I don't understand.  If slds-is-absolute is not a fix, should I just figure out how to avoid using position:absolute without breaking my component? Thanks.